# How to display bazaar version number in a latex document?

Tags: version-control, latex, bazaar, tex

I am using bazaar as a version control system for my research. I have many latex documents. I want to display the version number in all the .dvi files under bazaar.

Comment: You should probably change the title to something like: "How to display bazaar version number in a latex document?" which would be clearer and more likely to get a prompt answer.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to accomplish this will be to use `make` or a similar build manager to generate your .dvi files.

Your Makefile should include a new target called `version-number`:

```
version-number:
    bzr revno > VERSION.tex
```

and your .dvi targets should depend on `version-number`:

```
my-project.dvi: my-project.tex [OTHER STUFF] version-number
```

In your .tex files, at an appropriate place (in the header/footer, title block, PDF metainfo, etc) you would include the version number stored in VERSION.tex:

```
\input{VERSION}
```

When you set this up you should `bzr ignore VERSION.tex` so that it won't store its own version number, of course.

This is all based on a similar technique used for `git` in the [Common Lisp Quick Reference project](http://clqr.berlios.de/).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [bazaar keywords plugin](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/keywords-plugin.html) can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the latex [VC](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/vc) package successfully with Bazaar. It works using an external script that is called during compilation by \write18. This may seem overkill but it provides a lot of functionality and works well.